# Have Doxygen link type to file for C

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm creating a module in C. When I refer to that module in the documentation, I want a link to the header file, not the struct (because the functions and other useful information are at the file level).

The file my_iterator.h contains

```
  typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
  } my_iterator_t;
```

I would like references to `my_iterator` to create a link to `my_iterator.h`.  For example,

```
/**
  Create a new, specially configured my_iterator 
*/
my_iterator_t* special_factory_in_another_module();
```

Putting "`my_iterator.h`" in the documentation would create the correct link, but would sound strange.  Putting `my_iterator_t` in the documentation would sound better, but not link to a useful place.

Comment: I have the impression you are trying to do this the wrong way round. I would tag all functions that are part of the API to use `my_iterator_t` with the `@related` or `@memberof` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it almost worked.  The problem is that \relates works with classes only.  So, I can "relate" the function to my_iterator_t; but that puts the function with the "class" my_iterator_t, instead of the file my_iterator.h (which is where the remaining functions are documented).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a bit verbose, this does what I want:

```
/**
 * Create a new, specially configured [my_iterator](@ref my_iterator.h)
 */
my_iterator_t* special_factory_in_another_module();
```